# Unable to download excel file from web, using tidyverse and readxl

Tags: r, excel

I am working on coursera Getting and Cleaning Data R, assignment.

I have to download excel file from web. Read only specific rows and columns and store it in a dataframe. And then run some calucation.

I am unable to download the excel file. It shows downloaded but it has nothing. I followed this website:

https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl

https://readxl.tidyverse.org/articles/sheet-geometry.html

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(readxl)

>download.file(url="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx",
             destfile="./tidydata/week1q3.xlsx")
>list.files("./tidydata")

#I see the file created as week1q3.xlsx 16kb
#have to read rows 18:23 and columns 7:15.
#In a rectangle on a spreadsheet G18:O23
 
>dat<-read_excel("./tidydata/week1q3.xlsx", range="G18:O23")
```

*Error received: Error: Evaluation error: error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo*

I am unable to get anywhere with above logic. The downloaded packages- tidyverse and readxl are not helping to download   excel file from url: "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx"

Also, how to read specific rows and columns of spreadsheet into a Dataframe will Range= "G18:O23"  work?

Things to note is: the public website is "https" and excel when downloaded without R is "protected" worksheet. And I have an excel file name ending in "3". Not sure if any of these are causing the problem.

TIA

I have also tried to go the code below, but it needs rjava package.

```
row <- 18:23
col <- 7:15
dat <- read.xl("./tidydata/week1q3.xlsx", sheetIndex = 1, colIndex = col, rowIndex = row, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Whenever you include something like *"unable to get anywhere"*, it almost always helps to see what goes wrong: do you get an error or warning? Does it give you data but not the correct rows?

Comment: Yes, I am getting different error messages. Some about the Range for specific row, column. Some about the package. Error: Evaluation error: error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo

Comment: Another Message: trying URL 'https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx'
Content type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' length 16197 bytes (15 KB)
downloaded 15 KB

Comment: I think this is not an error `trying URL 'd396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/…' Content type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' length 16197 byte`. It is a message meaning it has downloaded the file. Can you check in your downloads folder if the file is present? On my system both the commands `download.file` and `read_excel` with `range` works fine.

Comment: Please just [edit] your question and put the errors in a code block immediately after the code that causes the error.

Comment: True @RonakShah, the above mentioned message, is not error. It creates a file of ~15kb, too small, with no data. But when I used the list.files(). It shows the newly created file. So the problem is with XL and related packages. I could download csv file- fine.

Comment: @r2evans, added the error to original question below code lines.

Comment: @nancysng00 I just ran your code, without changing anything: it works. It downloads a file with 15.8 KB, that file does contain the data and it can be read with `read.xl()`. If I download the file manually from that link, I get the exact same file. So if there is some issue, it is not in your code.

Comment: I tried read.xl() got error: cannot find read.xl. I do not have the packages needed to run read.xl. I downloaded the excel file and then ran dat<-read_excel("./tidydata/getdata_data_DATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx", range = "G18:O23") and it worked. Ran the calculation on dat and it calculated the answer. The problem is with download.file function in my code, download.file(url="https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx",destfile="./tidydata/week1q3.xlsx") Cannot open the downloaded file, now, by clicking on the file itself.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my understanding, you have to use mode = "wb" to make it work.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

download.file(url = "https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fdata%2FDATA.gov_NGAP.xlsx",
               destfile = "./week1q3.xlsx", mode = "wb")

dat <- read_excel("./week1q3.xlsx", range = "G18:O23")

dat

# A tibble: 5 x 9
    Zip CuCurrent PaCurrent PoCurrent Contact        Ext Fax          email Status
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        <lgl>  <dbl>
1 74136         0         1         0 918-491-6998     0 918-491-6659 NA         1
2 30329         1         0         0 404-321-5711    NA NA           NA         1
3 74136         1         0         0 918-523-2516     0 918-523-2522 NA         1
4 80203         0         1         0 303-864-1919     0 NA           NA         1
5 80120         1         0         0 345-098-8890   456 NA           NA         1
```